# How do you use the has_many_related relationship in mongoid 3+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am currently migrating from mongoid 2.0 to mongoid 3.0.5.  One of the relationships I have in an object is a `has_many_related`.  How do I migrate this over to mongoid 3.0.5?  I couldn't find any documentation for this via google searches, or in the mongoid.org and the two.mongoid.org websites.  Is there someplace I should be looking?

Here is the code:

```
  has_many_related :food_review do
    def find_or_initialize_by_user_id(user_id)
      criteria.where(:user_id => user_id).first || build(:user_id => user_id)
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: is food_review a part of the same collection or its a different collection. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761602/belongs-to-vs-belongs-to-related-has-many-vs-has-many-related) could help you

Comment: Both answers belows seems to be right, you should accept one of them or edit your post if it's not the case, with more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use has_many instead of has_many_related.

For example :

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field ...

  has_many :food_reviews

  def find_or_initialize_by_user_id(user_id)
    criteria.where(:user_id => user_id).first || build(:user_id => user_id)
  end
end

class FoodReview
  include Mongoid::Document
  field ...

  belongs_to :user
end
```

note the plural `has_many :food_reviews` and the singular `class FoodReview`. If you want to refer a singular review, just `use has_one :food_review` (see [Referenced 1-1](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_one))

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code of mongoid 2.0 has_many_related is just an alias to has_many:

```
➜  mongoid  git grep has_many_related
lib/ mongoid/relations/macros.rb:        alias :has_many_related :has_many
```

Just change it to :has_many and keep the code the same. There's an example of a block given to :has_many in the Mongoid Documentation [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html)